# Get the computed title in Nuxt 3

Tags: nuxtjs3

The Nuxt configuration defines a default `title` and a `titleTemplate`.
I would like to access the computed title from a Nuxt page.

The configuration looks like this:

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  app: {
    head: {
      title: "Default title",
      titleTemplate: "%s - Company"
    }
  }
})
```

Within a page I would like to define the title of the page as follows:

```
useHead({
  title: "Page title"
})
```

And just after access the computed title from the title template so in this case it would be `Page title - Company`.

And with this value I would like to define the `og:title` meta tag.

Do you know how to achieve this or a possible workaround even with a plugin?

The goal would be not to repeat things just to define the meta tags.

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same situation today, just in case someone needs this.

To achieve this, use the `titleTemplate` meta object. This will allow you to dynamically customize page titles on individual page.

Example,

`app.vue`

```js
<script setup>
useHead( {
  titleTemplate: ( titleChunk ) => {
    return titleChunk ? `${ titleChunk } - My Example App` : 'My Example App'
  }
} )
</script>
```

`~/pages/about.vue`

```js
<script lang="ts" setup>
useHead({
    title: 'About',
})
</script>
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>About</h1>
    </div>
</template>
<style scoped lang="css"></style>
```

The meta title of the About page is set to 'About'. But, if you view the About page, The meta title displayed is `About - My Example App`. That is because we set it in the `app.vue`. But if the `useHead` composable is not specified in a page, the title will be `My Example App`.

**Dynamic Meta Title**

You can also dynamically populate the meta title.

Example,

The title of the page must be from an API.

`~/server/api/articles.get.ts`

```js
export default defineEventHandler((event) => {
    return 'Article API'
})
```

In a page example

```js
<script lang="ts" setup>
const { data } = await useFetch('/api/articles')
useHead({
    title: data.value
})
</script>
<template>
    <main>
        <h1>{{ data }}</h1>
    </main>
</template>
```

Comment: It doesn't solve the issue of being able to programmatically retrieve the computed title on a page to be able to reuse it.

Answer (score -1):

This is how you can add title and page meta:

```
useHead({
    title: "My Dashboard",
    meta:[
    { hid: 'og:title', name: 'og:title', content: "My Dashboard" },]
})
```

Hope this is what you need.